# RavenDB Query Correct Results After Second Attempt

Tags: ravendb

When my C#, WPF UI starts, one of the tabs calls this code when loading. The most recent data displayed is 11-Feb-2012, even though there are InstallationSummary documents for 15-Feb-2012. When I hit the refresh button, this exact same code is called, only this time the most recent results are displayed. How can the same code produce two different results?

```
IQueryable<EntityBase> installationSummaries =
  QueryAndSetEtags(session => session.Query<InstallationSummary>()
  .Include(x => x.ApplicationServerId)
  .Include(x => x.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.ApplicationId)
  .Include(x => x.ApplicationWithOverrideVariableGroup.CustomVariableGroupId)
  .OrderByDescending(summary => summary.InstallationStart)
  .Take(numberToRetrieve));
```

Note: I'm having the exact same issue with another query. It seems as if I haven't queried in a while, I get the incorrect results. If I query again right after I just did it, I get the right results. I'm wondering if I have to create an index. There are over 10,000 InstallationSummary documents, and the performance is just fine. It's the accuracy that I'm having trouble with.

Comment: Try this - don't  load the results when tab loads. then see if it requires one or two refresh clicks to get correct results. Sounds like stale index.

Comment: @ZVenue: Thank you, but I don't need to try that because Daniel provided the answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like a stale index issue. Try to add this line and see if that helps

```
.Customize(x => x.WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOnNow())
```

**Update: It is better to use WaitForNonStaleResultsAsOnNow() than WaitForNonStaleResults()**

**Edit: Why is that?**
The reason is, that your query will create a temporary index that automatically will be deleted after some time of inactivity. Further, they will not survive a restart of RavenDB. Now you have a few option:

- promote the index to be permanent using the management studio
- create an index within your application and use that index when querying
- wait for raven to self optimize itself and promote the index automatically (this will only happen if the query will be run often enough, which seems unlikely in your case)
- use the .WaitForNonStaleResuls() option as outlined above (this is **worst** because it can have a very negative impact on application performance and there's no need to because the other options are much better)

Comment: Can a stale index still be the case, even after I've already retrieved the latest before? I can get the right results, close the app, reopen, and see old results again. Would a stale index cause that? This can happen even hours later... By the way, I'll try that in a bit...

Comment: That did the trick. Thank you. I just don't understand how/why an index could be stale, even after getting the latest, multiple times, over the last few hours. Maybe that's just how it is.

Comment: Makes total sense. Looks like I need to start learning Raven indexes. Thanks!

Comment: What's cool is that I can see the indexes in RavenDB Studio. So maybe I can just promote them to static/permanent.

Comment: Yes, that's the first option that I have outline above in my edit.

Comment: Do you know if that's what the Save icon does in RavenDB Studio? Does that promote it to a permanent index?

Comment: When I right-click on the index, a context dialog opens, but the only thing in the list is the word Silverlight.

Comment: @Daniel: If you're still looking at this thread, do you happen to know why I don't see Promote when I right-click the index in the RavenDB Studio? It just displays "Silverlight."

Comment: Maybe it's and old Browser or Silverlight version that has no support for right-click... I guess you're using one of the latest ravendb versions, right? You should then be able to right-click on the name of the index under the index-menu.

Comment: I'm using Raven build 573. I just upgraded IE to v9 and Silverlight to v5. Right-clicking still only shows "Silverlight." Grrr...

Comment: Ok, can you please report an issue here: http://issues.hibernatingrhinos.com/issues/RavenDB and maybe use Firefox or Chrome in the meantime.

Comment: Same issue with Chrome. Maybe I'm doing something wrong. I click on the Indexes tab at the top, then right-click on the temp index, and only see "Silverlight." Is that what I'm supposed to do? Since that wasn't working, I just created a new index using the same settings as the temp index. However, I had to set the Indexing dropdown from "No" to "Analyzed."

Comment: Bob, can you please send me a screenshot that shows _where_ you click?

Comment: @Daniel Oren (or whatever his name is -- I'm not sure what to call him) closed my issue with this comment: "Fixed in later builds, please upgrade to 616, where you can see that."